# How to sort array based on multiple fields?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have following array

```
var data =  [
{
  "orig": "FRA",
  "dest": "DRS",
  "ioi": "O",
  "dow": "4",
  "accessRight": "Private",
  "priority": "6"},
{
  "orig": "FRA",
  "dest": "IBZ",
  "ioi": "O",
  "dow": "257",
  "accessRight": "Global",
  "priority": "6"},
{
  "orig": "FRA",
  "dest": "AGP",
  "ioi": "I",
  "dow": "1",
  "accessRight": "Private",
  "priority": "7"},
{
  "orig": "FRA",
  "dest": "AGP",
  "ioi": "I",
  "dow": "5",
  "accessRight": "Global",
  "priority": "20"},

{
  "orig": "FRA",
  "dest": "IBZ",
  "ioi": "I",
  "dow": "1234567",
  "accessRight": "Private",
  "priority": "20"}
];
```

I want to sort data in such a way that after sorting any column other than "accessRight", I get result as array having accessRight = Private in beginning and other at end?

I tried it using this:

```
data.sort(function(a,b){
return b['accessRight'].localeCompare(a['accessRight']) ||
  Math.round(parseFloat(b['priority'])) <= 
Math.round(parseFloat(a['priority']))
  ? 1
  : -1;
})
```

Comment: ```data.sort((a,b)=>{
if(a.accessRight === 'Private') return -1;
return 0;
});```

Comment: Seems this has been closed before

Comment: The priority property has strings not numbers. I recommend converting them before comparing them

Comment: `b['accessRight'].localeCompare(a['accessRight'])` should be second condition in `||`. First, you need sort based on the column. IF both the column values are same, then it should consider the `accessRight` column

Comment: Also, you can just do `b.priority - a.priority`. It will be parsed to a number when subtraction is done.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data =  [
{
  "orig": "FRA",
  "dest": "DRS",
  "ioi": "O",
  "dow": "4",
  "accessRight": "Private",
  "priority": "6"},
{
  "orig": "FRA",
  "dest": "IBZ",
  "ioi": "O",
  "dow": "257",
  "accessRight": "Global",
  "priority": "6"},
{
  "orig": "FRA",
  "dest": "AGP",
  "ioi": "I",
  "dow": "1",
  "accessRight": "Private",
  "priority": "7"},
{
  "orig": "FRA",
  "dest": "AGP",
  "ioi": "I",
  "dow": "5",
  "accessRight": "Global",
  "priority": "20"},

{
  "orig": "FRA",
  "dest": "IBZ",
  "ioi": "I",
  "dow": "1234567",
  "accessRight": "Private",
  "priority": "20"}
];

let result = data.sort((a,b) =>{
  if(a.accessRight=='Private'){
    return -1
   }
   return 1
   //return a.accessRight.localeCompare(b.accessRight)
})

console.log(result)
```